# Portable Object Format (POF) serialization in .NET

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, oracle-coherence

I have a class called MyClass and pof configuration for this type (my-pof-config.xml).
I need to serialize an instance of MyType and then send it via JMS.

In Coherence Java API, there is ExternalizableHelper.toByteArray/fromByteArray. How can I do POF ([Portable Object Format](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH35UG/The+Portable+Object+Format)) serialization and deserialization in C#?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for making .NET clients for coherence? http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH35UG/Configuration+and+Usage+for+.NET+Clients There is a library that you can use for serialization/desrialization.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net you have `Tangosol.Util.SerializationHelper` which does the same as Java's `ExternalizableHelper`; something like this...
serialize:

```
ConfigrablePofContext serializer = new ConfigurablePofContext("...config file name...");
Binary binary = SerializationHelper.ToBinary(objectToSerialize, serializer);
byte[] bytes = binary.ToByteArray();
```

deserialize

```
ConfigrablePofContext serializer = new ConfigurablePofContext("...config file name...");
Binary binary = new Binary(byteArray);
Object deserializedValue = SerializationHelper.FromBinary(binary, serializer);
```